# ggplot not as to what I set it out to be

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to set my ggplot to a certain colour by the year.

```
All_Flights_Combined_DayOfWeek %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = Delay_Count:Total_Count) %>%
  mutate(Year2 = paste0(Year, " ", gsub("_", " ", name)),
         DayOfWeek = factor(DayOfWeek, levels = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = DayOfWeek, y = value, color = Year2, group = Year2)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(color = "Year", x = "DayOfWeek", y = "Number of Flights") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("2003 Delay count" = "red", 
                                "2004 Delay count" = "green", 
                                "2005 Delay count" = "blue", 
                                "2003 Total count" = "orange", 
                                "2004 Total count" = "yellow", 
                                "2005 Total count" = "purple"),
                     breaks = c("2003 Delay count",
                                "2004 Delay count",
                                "2005 Delay count",
                                "2003 Total count", 
                                "2004 Total count", 
                                "2005 Total count")) +
  ggtitle("Flight Count by DayOfWeek")
```

However, this is what R gave me.

[It's Grey.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlX4J.jpg)

This is my dataframe:

All_Flights_Combined_DayOfWeek
| Year| DayOfWeek| Delay_Count| Total_Count|
| --- | -------- | ---------- | ---------- |
|2003 |   Monday |     274690 |     959114 |
|2003 |  Tuesday |     237921 |     947126 |
|2003 |Wednesday |     256557 |     962100 |
|2003 | Thursday |     287079 |     952542 |
|2003 |   Friday |     303926 |     954701 |
|2003 | Saturday |     222247 |     811260 |
|2003 |   Sunday |     276785 |     901697 |
|2004 |   Monday |     367992 |    1044508 |
|2004 |  Tuesday |     314613 |    1033863 |
|2004 |Wednesday |     327136 |    1036521 |
|2004 | Thursday |     374378 |    1060245 |
|2004 |   Friday |     394566 |    1061447 |
|2004 | Saturday |     285131 |     903807 |
|2004 |   Sunday |     348867 |     988879 |
|2005 |   Monday |     376263 |    1048968 |
|2005 |  Tuesday |     327428 |    1037289 |
|2005 |Wednesday |     349048 |    1043208 |
|2005 | Thursday |     401044 |    1047749 |
|2005 |   Friday |     420650 |    1050985 |
|2005 | Saturday |     299717 |     919442 |
|2005 |   Sunday |     363711 |     992955 |

I have tried adding theme_classic() to the ggplot but to no avail.

Comment: In your data.frame `Count` is capitalized. In what you pass to `scale_color_manual` it isn't capitalized.

Comment: @Roland Thank you. It worked. I'm still quite new to programming so such stupid mistakes are often thought to be correct. Thank you. I'll be more careful next time.